# Помогите установить LLVM на Windows (застрял на 12 шаге инструкции, скриншоты прилагаю)

Tags: llvm

Потребовался LLVM (нужен для этой библиотеки:
https://github.com/informationsea/xlsxwriter-rs)

Система:
Windows 10 pro, 64-разрядная операционная система, процессор x64.
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz   3.20 GHz, 8Gb

Действую по этой инструкции:
https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html

До 11 шага все шло гладко. Так у меня выглядят папка LLVM на диске "С", путь к папке без пробелов согласно рекомендации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Так выглядит папка сборки:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Запускаю как администратор "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022".**
**Ввожу команду из 11 шага:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В CMake не понимаю что нужно делать, задаю поочередно оба пути  и жму "Generate":**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Получаю это:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а зачем Вы собираете llvm, если можно его просто скачать уже собранным?

Comment: Я обыскался готового варианта, но нигде не нашел. Я сталкиваюсь с этим впервые. Я изучаю программирование и для меня не совсем очевидно как поставить LLVM. Я буду благодарен вам если подскажете как поставить нужные библиотеке компоненты другим способом (не тем что я делаю).

Comment: вот - https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-14.0.4 - скорее всего Вам нужен файл LLVM-14.0.4-win64.exe (или 32битный, тут по надобностям)

Comment: Это сработало! Спасибо за решение проблемы!